# Tibolte/AgendaCalendarView How to import to android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-import

How can i import to my android [Tibolte AgendaCalendarView](https://github.com/Tibolte/AgendaCalendarView) ?
I have tried to add to my build.gradle (Module: app) the following:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

So far i have tried:

```
defaultConfig {
   multiDexEnabled true
}
```

with no luck :(

Comment: Still i have found no answer to this, i had to change library.. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this is because of the duplicate libraries,when you set

```
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and build in the messages u get the duplicate library name, remove the library from your dependency, in my case it was gson library and it worked.

Comment: I cant find where it tells the duplicate library, or it doesnt report anything in the messages ..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have multiple references to a library, you need to find out which library is conflicting.

Use this command to see your app's dependency tree

```
gradlew app:dependencies (for windows)
or
gradle app:dependencies (for linux)
```

where "app" is the name of the module of your app.

In my case the library was **com.google.collections**.
Then you change int the build.gradle file your compile statement as this

```
compile ('com.github.tibolte:agendacalendarview:1.0.3'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.collections'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In android Studio, you can go to file -> open -> Select the project folder -> Ok.

When you open this project in IDE. It will show the Error in gradle. To solve this, open Build.gradle file,and Remove or Comment this line

```
"apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'" .
```

Then Clean and Rebuild the project.